# Terraform resource with the ID already exists

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-azure

Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/azure-terraform-rg" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_resource_group" for more information.

`

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that the item you are trying to create all ready exists. Therefore terraform will not create it and instead you will need to import the reference into state; once this is done terraform will be able to manage the resource and any changes going forwards.

To import you will need to do something like this:

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.<NAME> <ID>
```

For example:

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.group_1 18923879383
```

Comment: I am importing id but now it says `Cannot import non-existent remote object`. Do you know how to add id in a state file?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right id, different services and products use a different "id". Sometimes this might be a number, or a "path/to/<id>". It really depends on what you are doing and what the product uses as an id
Take a look at the import section in the terraform docs, it will help you work out an ID https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account#import

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just using this as a resource instead of creating it, you may want to declare it as a variable on a var.tf page.

for instance:

```
    variable "resource_group_name" {
      default = "azure-terraform-rg"
    }
```